# How to create paragraph of particular type using JSONAPI?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am able to GET the data using endpoint "**site_url/jsonapi/paragraph/text**". But I am not able to create a new paragraph of type text. Its always giving me error "403 forbidden". I have tried all drupal permissions also i am using simple oauth and i am using admin token to POST.

```
Endpont :- site_url/jsonapi/paragraph/text
Request Type :- POST
Post Body :- {

"data": {
    "type": "paragraph--text",
    "attributes": {
        "field_text": {
            "value": "<p>ദുബായ് ∙ സാമ്പത്തിക അച്ചടക്കമില്ലാത്തവർക്കു കുരുക്കായി ക്രെഡിറ്റ് കാർഡുകൾ. കൃത്യമായി പണം തിരച്ചടയ്ക്കാതെ കുടിശിക പെരുകി കുടുക്കിലാകുന്നവരിൽ മലയാളികളുമേറെ. ബാധ്യത കൂടി ചിലർ വിട്ടുവീഴ്ചയ്ക്കായി ബാങ്കിനെ സമീപിക്കുമ്പോൾ മറ്റു ചിലർ രാജ്യത്തുനിന്നു മുങ്ങും. ഒരു കാർഡിന്റെ ബാധ്യത തീർക്കാൻ മറ്റൊരു ബാങ്കിൽ നിന്നുകൂടി ക്രെഡിറ്റ് കാർഡ് എടുത്ത് രണ്ടും തിരിച്ചടയ്ക്കാത്തവരുമുണ്ട്.</p>\r\n",
            "format": "basic_html",
            "processed": "<p>ദുബായ് ∙ സാമ്പത്തിക അച്ചടക്കമില്ലാത്തവർക്കു കുരുക്കായി ക്രെഡിറ്റ് കാർഡുകൾ. കൃത്യമായി പണം തിരച്ചടയ്ക്കാതെ കുടിശിക പെരുകി കുടുക്കിലാകുന്നവരിൽ മലയാളികളുമേറെ. ബാധ്യത കൂടി ചിലർ വിട്ടുവീഴ്ചയ്ക്കായി ബാങ്കിനെ സമീപിക്കുമ്പോൾ മറ്റു ചിലർ രാജ്യത്തുനിന്നു മുങ്ങും. ഒരു കാർഡിന്റെ ബാധ്യത തീർക്കാൻ മറ്റൊരു ബാങ്കിൽ നിന്നുകൂടി ക്രെഡിറ്റ് കാർഡ് എടുത്ത് രണ്ടും തിരിച്ചടയ്ക്കാത്തവരുമുണ്ട്.</p>"
        }
    },
    "relationships": {
        "paragraph_type": {
            "data": {
                "type": "paragraphs_type--paragraphs_type",
                "id": "6692c53b-f2f3-4a52-a18f-e59d94be3c88"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is always giving me 403 forbidden error. Am i doing anything wrong [image]?

Comment: Are you sure the user you use for authentication have permission to post to that URL? Are you sure that you have entered the correct username/password?

Comment: Yes everything was right. Problem was i was unaware of "Paragraph Type Permissions" module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was I didn't enable the "Paragraph Type Permission" module. Install it and go to drupal permissions.